# Apache not able to load javascript file

Tags: javascript, apache, webserver

Why this is the only script that is not loading? The other scripts load but this one don't.

When i open localhost everything works fine, but when i use the apache webserver, the script don't load.

[image: image-problem]

Comment: Did you look at the console? It should show a relevant error.

Comment: Look at the Network tab to see the request and response.